Calculate the conditional probabilities
Let $X$ and $Y$ be $X = [0, 1]$ and $Y = [0, 1]$, and let $(x, y)$ take the following values with equal probability ($1/4$):
$(0, 0)$,
$(0, 1)$,
$(1, 0)$,
$(1, 1)$.
Let
$$S = (x + y) \text{ mod }2$$
and  $$M = X \cdot Y$$
I need to find the conditional probabilities $P(S|M)$ and $P(M|S)$. I was told to use the Bayes' theorem, however I am not sure how to apply it to this task.
What I've got so far is that
$$P(M = 0) = 3/4,\quad P(M = 1) = 1/4,\quad P(S = 0) = P(S = 1) = 1/2$$
We also know that $P(A|B) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}$, so can't we just use this formula to find both $P(M|S)$ and $P(S|M)$?

$S$ and $M$ are random variables rather than events, so $P(S \mid M)$ is difficult to interpret.  But you can find $P(S=1 \mid M=1)$ or $P(S=1 \mid M=0)$, $P(S=0 \mid M=1)$, $P(S=0 \mid M=0)$ using conditional probability and in this case using counting methods.  The same thoughts apply to $P(M \mid S)$.

I would suggest first to create a table for the possible values of $S$ and $M$:




$Y=0$
$Y=1$




$X=0$
$S=0$, $M=0$
$S=1$, $M=0$


$X=1$
$S=1$, $M=0$
$S=0$, $M=1$



From here we can easily built the join distribution for $S$ and $M$ as $\dfrac{\text{# of cases needed}}{\text{# of cases occured}}$:




$M=0$
$M=1$




$S=0$
$\frac{1}{4}$
$\frac{1}{4}$


$S=1$
$\frac{1}{2}$
$0$



This yields all the necessary infomation: whichever condition you need, go  along the respective row / column.

Thank you, this makes it clearer. After this I guess I could try to use the Bayes' rule for discrete random variables
